# Will "dircolors" work here instead of " eval `"dircolors`"` "?

Tags: bash, ls, eval

I was checking .bashrc to set colors for ls comand and found this

```
export SHELL='/bin/bash'
 export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
 eval "`dircolors`"
 alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

Will there be any problem if i use `dircolors` instead of using it with `eval`? What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither `eval dircolors` nor `dircolors` will work.

What you need is:

```
eval "$(dircolors)"
```

(or the ancient form `` eval "`dircolors`" ``)

That is, you need to evaluate the output of `dircolors`. `dircolors` outputs code to be evaluated by the shell like:

```
LS_COLORS='...'
export LS_COLORS
```

That's the code you want to evaluate. `eval dircolors` is just like `dircolors`, so it will just run `dircolors` with its output not redirected, so that shell code above will just end up being displayed and not evaluated  by any shell.

Also if `$LS_OPTIONS` is meant to contain a list of `ls` options in shell syntax for instance accepting things like `--exclude='*~'`, then you'd need to define it as:

```
ls() {
  eval 'command ls '"$LS_OPTIONS"' "$@"'
}
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
alias ls='ls "${(Q@)${(z)LS_OPTIONS}}"'
```

If it's meant to contain a space-separated list of options instead, with bash 4.4+

```
ls() {
  local IFS=' '
  local -
  set -o noglob
  command ls $LS_OPTIONS "$@"
}
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
alias ls='ls ${(s: :)LS_OPTIONS}'
```

Comment: Can you plz explain why that is so?

Comment: @AbinashDash, see edit.

Comment: Okay. Now it looks like a long answer... :D

Comment: I misunderstood things. As  executing `dircolors` in shell gives the output `LS_COLORS='...'` and `export LS_COLORS` , I thought those are evaluated by themselves(after executing `dircolors`) and it's only in printing what commands are executed. Thanks for clearing my doubts. Great answer.