# Effect of dircolors

Tags: bash, ls, colors

What does `dircolors` affect.  Is it for the `ls` command only ?  Should `dircolors` be called before defining `alias ls='ls --color'`?

Comment: From `man 1 dircolors`: `dircolors - color setup for ls`

Comment: There's a good explanation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427439/65304)

Comment: I am still unsure about what the order of the calls should be.  Have also defined `LS_COLORS` but without exporting the variable, before evaluating the `dircolours` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dircolors` outputs code meant to be interpreted by a shell. Without option or with the `-b` option, that's meant for Bourne-like shells such as ksh, zsh or bash and all modern `sh`, with `-c`, that's for `csh` or `tcsh`, it doesn't support any other shell².

The output code instructs the shell to set the `$LS_COLORS` environment variable, that variable is queried by the GNU implementation of `ls` to customize its colouring output when invoked with the `--color` option.

In Bourne²-like shells, you'd do:

```
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
```

To evaluate the output of `dircolors`

In (t)csh:

```
eval "`dircolors -c`"
```

The `$LS_COLORS` variable must be set before `ls --color` is invoked but has no incidence on the definition of the aliases or functions that use `ls`. So the:

```
alias ls 'ls --color' # (t)csh
alias ls='ls --color' # Korn-like shells
ls() command ls --color "$@" # most Bourne-like shells
ls() { command ls --color "$@"; } # all Bourne-like shells
```

May be put before or after that call to `eval`, it makes no difference.

Since it updates the environment, it's enough to put the `eval` line in your `~/.profile` / `~/.login` (or equivalent login session customisation file for your login shell) so it's set only once per login session, while the aliases / functions should be set via the shell customisation file (`~/.zshrc`, `~/.cshrc`, `~/.bashrc`...).

In any case, if you don't use `dircolors`, you'll still get colours, just the default ones. When using `dircolors` without a customization file, you'll get different defaults.

You can edit those defaults by doing:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.config/dircolors
```

Edit that file and change the line in your shell startup file with:

```
eval "$(dircolors ~/.config/dircolors)"
```

---

<sup>¹ There are ways around it for other shells, but you're on your own then. For instance, with recent `fish` versions, you could do `set -x LS_COLORS "$(sh -c "$(dircolors -b)"'; printf %s "$LS_COLORS"')"`</sup>

<sup>² except in the Bourne-shell itself that didn't have `$(...)` but the Bourne shell is not in use any longer and its `` `...` `` equivalent is deprecated.</sup>

Comment: Yes, I am using the `-b` option.  Is it contradictory to set `LS_COLORS` and then executing `dircolors` with a customization file ?

Comment: @Hovlar, `eval "$(dircolors -b)"` sets `$LS_COLORS`. `dircolors` outputs `LS_COLORS='...'; export LS_COLORS`, so if you also have a `LS_COLORS=...` that will indeed conflict (override or be overridden depending on whether it's after or before) with that.